# Prepared Statement in MySQL Connector

Tags: c++, prepared-statement, mysql-connector

I want to do a prepared statement like this:

```
pstmt=conn->prepareStatement("UPDATE partidos SET i?=? WHERE ID=?");
pstmt->setInt(1,lazo);
pstmt->setString(2,texto[lazo]);
pstmt->setInt(3,var);
pstmt->execute();
```

"lazo" is a variable in a for loop, texto[lazo] is a variable and var is another int variable.

When I run this query, it throws an exception: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'i?=? WHERE ID=?' at line 1".

It seems that it doesn't replace the '?'.

I tried with stringstreams, but the problem didn't fix.

Thanks.

Comment: This part doesn't look right...SET i?=?  Are you sure it is not SET i=?  Otherwise your partitos table would need a field called i?

Comment: No, per example a field would be i1,i2,i3,i4,i5... That's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I opted for this.

```
stringstream stmtvar;
stmtvar << "UPDATE PARTIDOS SET minuto" << lazo << "='" << texto[lazo] << "' WHERE ID=" << var;
stmt->executeUpdate(stmtvar.str());
```

It worked perfectly

Comment: This is unsafe though as all inputs might need to be sanitized first for SQL Injection.

Comment: @Dalzhim You're right, but all the variables that I'm using ("lazo", "texto[lazo]" and "var") are internal variables that the program uses, so there's no user input there. But I agree with you, this isn't the best approach when working with usernames and passwords.

Comment: Remember that those variables not being exposed to user input might be true at the moment the sql statements are originally written, but that might change during maintenance without the appropriate escaping routines being used. In all cases, PreparedStatements are the best option.

Comment: I would be so happy If I get the right method. Till then I think I should use this workaround. No other go !